# how to get json field value in template?

Tags: python, django, json

I had generated json with my model objects and sended responce to the template.
then i wanted to process json getting fields of my model with javascript.
Python code is like that:

```
return json_serializer.serialize(queryset, ensure_ascii=False)
```

js in template is here:

```
 function my_js_callback(data){
    alert(data) //1
    item=data[0]
    alert(item) //2
}
```

1 - gives me [object Object], [object Object],...
2 - gives [object Object]

And this:

```
alert(item['title'])
alert(item.title)
alert(item["title"])
```

All give me errors. How can i get my title?

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake.
My JSON was like several levels dict and i couldn't find my field beacuse it was in dictionary named fields in the JSON object first level dictionary.
Now it is okay:

```
var key="title"
var item=data["fields"]
alert(item[key])
```